# search columns in different spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Okay, I will try to explain in words what Im trying to accomplish, hoping that someone will be able push me in the right direction.

I have two different google spreadsheets:

1. One named ”Ads_sent_in” containing a couple of different columns that is automatically filled in by a PHP file on my website.. (its a list of file uploads that is being uploaded through a web-form). These are clients that uploads adverts (pdf’s) that are to be put in a magazine for print.

One of the columns in ”Ads_sent_in” is called ”Ordernumber” and contains a specific, unique number for the advert.

2. the other spreadsheet named ”Magazine_name_03-2019”. This is where all the adverts a placed on the different pages in the magazine, all in one spreadsheet. Each advert is represented by 1 row and 3 columns of info/data.

They are: Advertisers name/client name - advert size -  ordernumber (Same number as in the other spreadsheet above in point 1.

Now,

I want do make a script that will be able to search the ”Ads_sent_in” spreadsheet for the ”ordernumber”, and find the same ”ordernumber” in the other spreadsheet ”Magazine_name_03-2019”.
If there is a match, the textcolor of ”ordernumber” (and also if possible, the cell which is always located one step/column to the left of where ”ordernumber” is) should be changed to green.
If no match, do nothing.

Is this possible?

=============================

## EDIT

I pick up the ordernumber from the *Ads_sent_in* sheet using this bit of code:

```
var ordernumber = sheet_Ads.getRange(sheet_Ads.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
```

After that I think all I need is a function that will search the *Magazine_name_03-2019* sheet for the **ordernumber** I get from above..

The best scenario would be if that function could search a whole spreadsheet (both columns and rows) for the **ordernumber** and return the cell (for example 'D5'). I don't need any values returned, I just need to know where this **ordernumber** is located, in what cell in the *Magazine_name_03-2019* sheet.

Then store the cell location (for example 'D5') in:

```
var ordernumber_loc = sheet_Magazine_name_0319.getActiveCell ?
```

I'd like to back off two columns to the left of the **ordernumber_loc** above if possible and store it in another variable

```
var client_cell_loc = ordernumber_loc - "2 columns"
```

From there on I want to change the color of **client_cell_loc** text to green and make it bold:

```
var style = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
  .setForegroundColor("green")
  .setBold(true)
  .build();
range.setTextStyle(style);
```

(Sorry if its a bit messy, I dont know much about coding.. but want to learn :)

Comment: Get the destination values, then inspect them. See `SpreadsheetApp.openById` and `Range#getValues`

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. Steps could be as follows -

1. Input ordernumber using a prompt
2. Search in **Ads_sent_in**
3. Search in **Magazine_name_03-2019**
4. If match, color cell/row

Comment: Thanks, I updated my post above, trying to explain a bit better what Im trying to do..